# Sql server security : User 'SA'

Tags: sql-server

Since a few week, there is a lot of attempt of connection on user 'SA' on my Database, Sql server.

*Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: xxx.xx.xx.xx]*

The IP adresses are all from China.
I think that a hacker try to connect to my Database.

**What is the best practices to protect user 'SA' against hackers ?**

I need to connect to the Database with *Sql server authentification mode*.
If i disable the user 'SA', can i still connect with Sql authentification ?

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Disabling `sa` will not affect other logins.  It's probably a bad idea to run a database connected to the internet.  Most databases are behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable SA and enable it only to connect from internal network.
Either you can put your DB behind a firewall.

Comment: We have create software for our clients that needs to connect to this database. So we can't connect only from internal network.